# Can't get contact on Sitecore EXM 9.3

Tags: exm

I am using Sitecore 9.3. After I run the EXM campaign.I go to the email and click to see online version.

I can get the `ec_eq` query string on this.
Then I tried to dycrypt it but can't get contact information on this (`ec_contact_id`).

Here my code:

```
QueryStringEncryption.GetDefaultInstance().TryDecrypt(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString, out NameValueCollection result);
```

I need to get contact then modify some information for it.
Any suggestion on this case?

Comment: Can you add more details regarding where you are trying to decrypt the querystring? If you take a look at https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/23697/get-access-to-contact-id-in-exm-email the httpBeginRequest pipeline decrypts ec_eq and populates the EXMContext object.

Comment: I created a custom <mvc.resultExecuted> pipeline. In this process, I get the param ec_eq then try to decrypt it with code above but the result after decrypt only see keys bellow:  
  [0] "sc_itemid"
  [1] "sc_lang" 
  [2] "sc_pd_view"
  [3] "ec_message_id" 
  [4] "ex_id_s" 
  [5] "ex_id_i" 
  [6] "ec_lang" 
  [7] "ec_tvi" 
  [8] "ec_emailid" 
Can't see contact information.
Pls let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the contact ID, you can only get the identifier that was used to email the contact. Usually this contact is the Alias, `Sitecore.XConnect.Constants.AliasIdentifierSource` identifier.

In your layout/rendering, add these two lines.

```
 var source = ExmContext.ContactIdentifier.Source;
 var identifier = ExmContext.ContactIdentifier.Identifier;
```

That will get you the identifier used and the value. From there you can find the contact by identifier.

```
public ListSubscriberFacetModel GetContactByIdentifier(string source, string identifier)
{
    using (XConnectClient client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
    {
        try
        {
            var facetsToGet = new List<string>
            {
                ListSubscriptions.DefaultFacetKey
            };

            var existingContact = GetContact(source, identifier, client, facetsToGet.ToArray());

            if (existingContact == null)
                return null;

            // You have the contact Id here
        }
        catch (XdbExecutionException ex)
        {
            this.errorService.LogError(ex, this);
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private Contact GetContact(string source, string identifier, XConnectClient client, string[] facets)
{
    var reference = new IdentifiedContactReference(source, identifier);

    var existingContact = client.Get(reference, new ContactExpandOptions(facets));

    return existingContact;
}
```